# Ansible - negative filter question

Tags: ansible, filter

I am writing an Ansible playbook that grants and rejects access to some dirs.
Base is a list of user dictionaries:

```
users:
  - {name: 'user1', dirs: ['dir1', 'dir2']}
  - {name: 'user2', dirs: ['dir1', 'dir3']} 
  - {name: 'user3', dirs: []}
```

As a helper fact, I created a list of all dirs occurring in any of the user records.

Now I want to transform this list into two new lists:

```
dirs_allowed:
  - {'dir1': ['user1', 'user2']}
  - {'dir2': ['user1']}
  - {'dir3': ['user2']}
```

this one is easy, but I cannot find a solution for this one:

```
dirs_forbidden:
 - {'dir1': ['user3']}
 - {'dir2': ['user2', 'user3']}
 - {'dir3': ['user1', 'user3']}
```

So, my question is: How can I get a list of all users who don't have the current dir (=item in a with_items loop over all dirs) in their 'dirs' attribute?

It is certainly possible to do it somehow with helper variables/facts or 'when'-conditions on the task but I would really like to transform the lists themselves because I want to learn how to deal with such complex transformations.
The idea behind it is to provide just a single dict as input and extract everything needed for the particular tasks from this dict, without lots of set_fact-tasks in between which would make the playbook difficult to read and possibly fail because of undefined variables if the task is moved to a place where the intermediate variables are not (yet) set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters). For example

```
    - set_fact:
        users_all: "{{ users|json_query('[].name') }}"
    - set_fact:
        dirs_forbidden: "{{ dirs_forbidden|default([]) + [
          {(item.keys()|list|first):
           (users_all|difference(item.values()|list|first))}] }}"
      loop: "{{ dirs_allowed }}"
    - debug:
        var: dirs_forbidden
```

give

```
    "dirs_forbidden": [
        {
            "dir1": [
                "user3"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "dir2": [
                "user2", 
                "user3"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "dir3": [
                "user1", 
                "user3"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

---

FWIW. Working with dictionaries makes the code simpler in this case. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        users_all: "{{ users|json_query('[].name') }}"
    - set_fact:
        dirs_all: "{{ users|
                       json_query('[].dirs')|flatten|unique }}"
    - set_fact:
        dirs_allowed: "{{ dirs_allowed|default({})|
                          combine({item: users|json_query(query)}) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?dirs.contains(@, '{{ item }}')].name"
      loop: "{{ dirs_all }}"
    - debug:
        var: dirs_allowed
    - set_fact:
        dirs_forbidden: "{{ dirs_forbidden|default({})|
                            combine({item: (users_all|difference(dirs_allowed[item]))}) }}"
      loop: "{{ dirs_all }}"
    - debug:
        var: dirs_forbidden
```

give

```
    "dirs_allowed": {
        "dir1": [
            "user1", 
            "user2"
        ], 
        "dir2": [
            "user1"
        ], 
        "dir3": [
            "user2"
        ]
    }
```

```
    "dirs_forbidden": {
        "dir1": [
            "user3"
        ], 
        "dir2": [
            "user2", 
            "user3"
        ], 
        "dir3": [
            "user1", 
            "user3"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Not exactly what I was looking for (I tried to do it without any intermediate facts directly from the users list to both dirs_allowed and dirs_forbidden without dependence on which to calculate first) but certainly very helpful! And my original goal could be achieved by some replacements if necessary.